# Data is converting into some weird data in asp.net

Tags: sql, asp.net

I am uploading from Excel into database by creating type in the database 
and then inserting all the data into another table.

For example:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[temp_tbl_vendor] AS TABLE([VendorCode] [varchar](10) NULL,
[BillDt] [varchar](12) NULL )

create proc myproc_bulkinsert
(@venid int, @temptable temp_tbl_vendor readonly) 
as
begin
insert into mynewtab select *from temp_tbl_vendor 
end
```

Everything is working fine only the problem is that Excel data that is `20150702` is changing to `2.01507e002`.

Comment: Check the format of that column in Excel. Change it to Number

Comment: Format that column in excel as Number or Text and check it again.

Comment: Isn't 20150702 a date value? And which data type do you want in the table?

Comment: @jarlh: it depends how you read it. It can be an integer as well.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of issues in your design.

1. Never store date as a string in the database. Date is a date and should be stored in a DateTime field.

Change ***temp_tbl_vendor*** to:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[temp_tbl_vendor] AS TABLE([VendorCode] [varchar](10) NULL,
[BillDt] DATETIME NULL )
```

Change corresponding column in ***mynewtab*** to a `DATETIME` field

2. You need to convert spreadsheet column to a date type and/or more importantly  read it into a date field before inserting into the **temp_tbl_vendor**.